# SUM condicional Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Estou usando o JasperSoft Studio. Em Summary desejo exibir o totalizador de um field, porém usando a função SUM(que o JS fornece quando arrasto o field) não consigo somar por uma dada condição.

O que eu queria era algo como, somar o campo $F{valor} quando $F{ocorrência} fosse diferente de a "28".

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável no seu relatório colocando o campo `Calculation` para `Sum` e o campo `Value Class Name` para `java.lang.Integer`.
No campo `Expression` coloque a seguinte condição:  `$F{ocorrência} == 28 ? $F{valor} : new Integer(0)`

Esta solução irá funcionar mas leve em consideração que a lógica de testes mais complexos não deve estar no relatório e sim no seu código.
Se você tiver que fazer muitas condições como esta pense na possibilidade de calcular isso antes de passar os dados para o jasper e informá-los já calculados através de parâmetro.